# Для чего pattern Composite?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте. Обьясните пожалуйста, для каких задач можно использовать этот паттерн?

Перечитал множество источников но понять не могу зачем он нужен.

Comment: Ну, так, почитайте ещё: http://habrahabr.ru/post/85166/

Answer (score 2):

для каких задач: для любых задач, где требуется наличие иерархии в структуре данных. насколько банальных примеров: парсинг и хранение XML, класы для хранения структуры какой-то организации, построение дерева dependencies модулей/либ/классов для определения очередности при билде "чего-то там".

Answer (score 0):

windows forms (.NET), swing (java)